# Grape-Swagger not listing methods contained in a grape-based API

Tags: ruby, swagger, ruby-grape, api-doc

I'm using the [`grape-swagger`](https://github.com/tim-vandecasteele/grape-swagger) gem and I'm being unable to get a Grape-based API properly described in Swagger.
Using: `grape (0.11.0)` and `grape-swagger (0.10.1)`

When I enable  the Swagger json listing I get this output listing all endpoints but not the methods contained in each endpoint.

My output:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "v0",
  "swaggerVersion": "1.2",
  "produces": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "apis": [
    {
    "path": "/version.{format}",
    "description": "Operations about versions"
    },
    {
    "path": "/ping.{format}",
    "description": "Operations about pings"
    },
    {
    "path": "/users.{format}",
    "description": "Operations about users"
    },
    {
    "path": "/company.{format}",
    "description": "Operations about companies"
    },
    {
    "path": "/merchants.{format}",
    "description": "Operations about merchants"
    }
  ],
  "info": {}
}
```

I've also added CORS Allowance in config.ru like this:

```
require 'rack/cors'
use Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :delete, :options]
  end
end
```

Any clue on how to get methods for each endpoint listed inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just not how Swagger 1.2 works.

Assuming you get the above JSON at `/api-docs`, try opening `/api-docs/version.json` for example to see the operations for `version`. Of course, if it's not hosted under `/api-docs`, just replace that part with whichever path segment is actually used.

Comment: For some stupid reason I was totally expecting a unified response JSON file.
Now everything makes sense and swagger-ui works perfectly using this output.
Thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth, Swagger 2.0 is indeed a single file. No idea when grape-swagger would release support for it, but you should be on the lookout for it.

Comment: Good to know that of Swagger 2.0. My guess is that the multiple-file approach comes from the WSDL days, which is like that, and can somehow be called the XML antecesor of Swagger.